# Arithmetic operations on Knuth arrow notation

Tags: notation, arithmetic, computer-science

I want to create a game that explores massive numbers (on the scale of [Tree 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%27s_tree_theorem), [G64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham%27s_number), etc.). Normal scientific notation is too small, so common BigNum or alike libraries aren't capable of this.
I would imagine numbers would be stored in arrow notation, notably [up arrow notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_up-arrow_notation).

Representing these numbers is simple, but my question is how to do operations on them. For example, these up arrow notated numbers:

$a ↑↑↑ b + c ↑↑↑ d$

$a↑^nb + c↑^kd$

$(a↑↑↑b)*(c↑↑↑d)$

I'm also interested in arithmetic with chain arrow notated numbers too. ([chained arrow notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway_chained_arrow_notation))

Comment: As I understand it, these numbers are so huge (and so separated in magnitude) that low-level operations don't make a noticeable difference to the larger of the two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of adding, the general case will be that one term is massively larger than the other and no simpler form will be available. Even where comparability might be possible, how would you deal with the simplest case $a^b+c^d$?

In multiplying think about $a^b\cdot c^d$ - what would be your goal for this.

If you can explain what you are aiming for in these simple cases, that would help give a clue as to what you are imagining. However, I suspect you are looking for something which doesn't exist.

Comment: You are completely right actually. I can create an illusion of numbers going up by increasing the mantissa or eventually adding more arrows. At this scale, precision doesn't matter.